# Разрешение экрана онлайн

Tags: python-3.x

совсем недавно я узнал о том, что браузер отправляет разрешение экрана сайтам которые посещает пользователь.
Как раз сейчас я пишу небольшой инструмент, который поможет узнать как можно больше информации о том, кто и с какого устройства посещает тестовый сайт.
И у меня возник вопрос, каким образом я могу узнать разрешение экрана устройства которое посетило мой сайт ?
Что у браузера нужно запросить ?
Пишу на питоне.

Comment: `разрешение экрана устройства ` можно послать через js (например через ajax + свойства window.innerWidth и window.innerHeight), а так, мне кажется в протоколе HTTP это не передается.